# Ubuntu 16.10: Run Elasticsearch as a deamon or just start it on system startup

Tags: elasticsearch, daemon, ubuntu-16.04

My Elasticsearch server is already running as a service. I can start and run it like so:

```
sudo service elasticsearch start 
sudo service elasticsearch stop
```

However I would like to have it always running. Currently I need to start it manually on every system boot. I have already tried to register it as a deamon with the following commands:

```
sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 
sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10
```

I still need to start the Elasticsearch server manually. What do I need to do to run Elasticsearch as a daemon or start it at all on system startup? Since it is my local development environment, I would not need Elasticsearch as a daemon. I just need to start it on the startup of my system.

Comment: You went through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290304/how-to-keep-elastic-search-running-on-linux-server) SO ?

Comment: Yes, this was the thread from which I have followed the steps. I have created also the file at **/etc/init.d/elasticsearch**. How can I debug this?

Comment: Has anybody a clue..?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've found the answer or not (I'm assuming so), but for anyone who has not; you can use:

```
sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
```